# tabs position on kivymd

Tags: kivy, kivymd

hi I'm trying to insert two tabs in my kivymd project but when I put them in "MDTabs" they appear on the left of the page and I can't find a way to put them in the center with the same size

```
MDTabs:
                size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
                halign: "center"
                Tab: 
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
                    halign: "center"
                    icon: 'ab-testing'
                    text: 'jfa'
                    title: "mfnvjkf"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "njdvslns"
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        halign: "center"
                Tab: 
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
                    halign: "center"
                    icon: 'ab-testing'
                    text: 'jfhbjva'
                    title: "mf"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "njs"
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        halign: "center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `kv`:

```
<MDTabs>
    carousel: carousel
    tab_bar: tab_bar
    anchor_y: "top"
    background_palette: "Primary"

    _line_x: 0
    _line_width: 0
    _line_height: 0
    _line_radius: 0

    on_size:
        root._update_padding(layout)

    MDTabsMain:
        padding: 0, tab_bar.height, 0, 0

        MDTabsCarousel:
            id: carousel
            lock_swiping: root.lock_swiping
            ignore_perpendicular_swipes: True
            anim_move_duration: root.anim_duration
            on_index: root.on_carousel_index(*args)
            on__offset: tab_bar.android_animation(*args)

    MDTabsBar:
        id: tab_bar
        padding: root.tab_padding
        carousel: carousel
        scrollview: scrollview
        layout: layout
        size_hint: None, None                  # changed to allow centering
        width: min(layout.width, root.width)   # changed to allow centering
        elevation: root.elevation
        height: root.tab_bar_height
        md_bg_color:
            self.theme_cls.primary_color \
            if not root.background_color else \
            root.background_color

        MDTabsScrollView:
            id: scrollview
            do_scroll_x: False if layout.width <= self.width else True

            MDGridLayout:
                id: layout
                rows: 1
                size_hint_y: 1
                adaptive_width: True
                on_size: root._update_padding(layout)

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: root.underline_color
                    Line:
                        width: dp(2)
                        rectangle: [0, 0, layout.width, dp(2)]
                    Color:
                        rgba:
                            root.theme_cls.accent_color \
                            if not root.indicator_color else \
                            root.indicator_color
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        group: "Indicator_line"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: 0, root.tab_indicator_height
                        radius: [0,]
                    Line:
                        width: dp(2)
                        rounded_rectangle:
                            [ \
                            root._line_x, \
                            self.pos[1], \
                            root._line_width, \
                            root._line_height, \
                            root._line_radius \
                            ]
```

This is the `kv` for `MDTabs` from `kivymd` version 1.0.2 with changes commented. If you are using a different version of `kivymd`, you may need to adjust the above `kv`.